# How to allow website access to certain users

Tags: php

I am trying to restrict access to a webpage and only users that add certain query string can have access.

https://example.com/web/?allow=your_key

```php
if ( isset($_GET['allow']) || !empty($_GET['allow']) ) {

    if ( 'your_key' !== htmlspecialchars($_GET['allow']) ) {
        die('You have no access to view this url.');
    }

} else {
    die('You have no access to view this url.');
}
```

Is it secure to use that?

Comment: Not even a little bit

Comment: If your key is long enough it will be hard to guess it. But a login system would be much better. So this isn't really a good approache.

Comment: If a user access that page, the URL (including the query string) will be stored in plain text in the users history so anyone that has access to that computer can get the "allow"-string. How secure do you need it to be? Is it sensitive information or just _"I rather not let people see it but if they do.. so be it"_?

Comment: _“Is it secure to use that?”_ - if “allow anyone who knows this code access” is the only requirement you want to fulfill, and that requirement stays the same after someone, say, posted the URL including the code on social media or something like that … then probably, yes.

Comment: It's a webpage that has company's sensitive information. I don't want to use a login system. So I guess I must restrict it by our office static ip

Comment: _"It's a webpage that has company's sensitive information. I don't want to use a login system."_ - If it's sensitive company info, then you should do what you need, not what you want. Restricting to your company's IP address will probably go a long way. Just make sure that non-company people connected to your WiFi/guest network (if you have one) still can't access it. There are rarely a single simple solution when it comes to security.

Comment: You can also use some basic auth for a web-server like [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/)

Comment: @freeek - That can be used on any web server since you can implement it using PHP. However, Basic Auth is not considered secure. At least not if you're not using https (but that goes for all log ins).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson of course, but it's more secure, then proposed approach. Also, it's quite simple. Security is a hard question, almost nothing is 100% secured, because social engineering exists :)

Comment: If you want to use the site in the company and protect it, why not just set up a local server in the office, behind your firewall? Unless you expect heavy traffic on the site, any old computer would probably be ok.

Answer (score 1):

this is an insecure approach because the query string is sent as part of the GET request. This means it can be logged or stored in a user's history and someone with access to either the logs or the user's history will get access to the site.

In addition, in this scenario, you would have to change the source code to change the key.

Answer (score -2):

```php
function getUserIP() {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { //check ip from share internet
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {   //to check ip is pass from proxy
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    } else {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    }

    return $ip;
}

$getIP = getUserIP();

$whitelist_ips = array(
    '10.10.10.10',
    '20.20.20.20'
);

if ( ! in_array($getIP, $whitelist_ips) ) {
    die('You have no access to view this url.');
}
```

That works better for me.
Is this insecure?

Comment: Yes, not secure.  The `HTTP_` headers can easily be forged.

Comment: I think, if you want it fast and secure, use some framework for this. As an example you can use [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security) security module.